# Geoserver - Legend - Delete group text to keep only that of the element

Tags: text, icons, legend, geoserver, group

I would like to delete the group or subgroup text in the caption to keep only that of the element next to the symbol.

How can I do this?

See screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQbon.png)

Comment: As I said on gis.Se you can not unless you request the individual rules as it is the name of the layer

Comment: So where and how do individual rules. With GetLegendGraphic or even the decorations in the xml there is no such LEGEND_OPTIONS option, the why I am asking. How would you concretely do otherwise do not answer the question. Thank you

Comment: You would need to use a getlegendgraphic request, the documentation is pretty clear I think. There is no way to do using the decorations but you could add code to do it.

Comment: I don't see this option in LEGEND_OPTIONS, if you have it please mention it here. To code, would it be in style-editor-legend.xml? Thank you

Comment: It is part of the `getLegendGraphic` request - see https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getlegendgraphic